# JUnit Theories: Why can't I use Lists (instead of arrays) as DataPoints?

Tags: unit-testing, junit

I've started using the new(ish) JUnit [Theories](http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2010/01/31/new-feature-of-junit-theories/) feature for parameterizing tests. If your Theory is set up to take, for example, an `Integer` argument, the `Theories` test runner picks up any `Integer`s marked with `@DataPoint`:

```
@DataPoint
public static Integer number = 0;
```

as well as any `Integer`s in arrays:

```
@DataPoints
public static Integer[] numbers = {1, 2, 3};
```

or even methods that return arrays like:

```
@DataPoints 
public static Integer[] moreNumbers() { return new Integer[] {4, 5, 6}; };
```

but not in `List`s. The following does not work:

```
@DataPoints 
public static List<Integer> numberList = Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9);
```

**Edit**: It looks like other collections are not supported either, as this does not work.

```
@DataPoints 
public static Collection<Integer> numberList = new HashSet<Integer>() {{
  add(7);
  add(8);
  add(9);
}};
```

Am I doing something wrong, or do `List`s, `Set`s, etc. really not work? Was it a conscious design choice not to allow the use of `Collection`s as data points, or is that just a feature that hasn't been implemented yet? Are there plans to implement it in a future version of JUnit?

(I'm currently using version 4.8.1 whereas the newest version is 4.8.2 but [it looks like](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/doc/ReleaseNotes4.8.2.html) this is not something that was added in 4.8.2)

Comment: As a side-note, I don't see a tag for this "Theories" feature. I assume the [`theory`] tag is for theoretical questions about things like big-O complexity and such. Please feel free to retag.

Comment: +1 Seems quite odd. Did you try any other Collection types?

Comment: Just tried using a `Set` and updated the question. That doesn't work either, whether you declare it as `Set` or `Collection`.

Comment: I've added this as an issue: http://github.com/KentBeck/junit/issues/issue/110

I'll keep an eye on that issue and see if anyone posts a comment with some more information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked at the issue, and it seems there is now a pending commit for it. The reason that it wasn't in there seems to be simply that nobody asked for it and it's quite complex to do (as you've proven in [your patch](http://github.com/MatrixFrog/junit))

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I should have added a comment to this SO answer saying that I did manage to figure out a solution (though it's certainly not perfect) and then sent a pull request on github.

Comment: I was not sure, if putting a comment in 3 years old post is a good thing. But I just wish to know, whats the update on this issue. This issue is still not resolved in latest Mockito version. Also link to issue mentioend above does not exists anymore.